# maven execute java command

Tags: maven

I want to execute a jar file with parameters from maven. The command I want to execute is listed below. I have the `perf4j` jar file in the dependency. The `times.log` file is in they filesystem.

```
java -jar perf4j-0.9.16.jar times.log
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had looked at maven exec plugin but wasn't sure how and where to specify the jar file name, hence thanks for your responses, but I was looking at a little more info especially with jar file. With some trial and error the following worked. I had to find the main class to use from the jar file. `mvn install` runs the file and produces the following output:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.perf4j.LogParser</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>InlineLogging.log</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look @ [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html)

Comment: where do i specify the jar file and the -jar option

Comment: From your description, I suspect you need it to run in a separate VM. Thus, you will need to use the exec:exec goal and specify "java" as the executable, passing the jar file and the rest of the parameters as arguments. All parameters that the exec plugin provides are described here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

first

```
mvn clean install
```

than

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.java.App" -Dexec.args="Args"
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to do ? Using a jar (which is a dependency) to monitor your app ?

Did you took a look at [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) ?

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>maven</executable>
          <!-- optional -->
          <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-X</argument>
            <argument>myproject:dist</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```